# Run Script and display its output on the remote node

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

I want to run an un-ending script and want to see the output on the remote node only. Is that possible ?

maybe sth like:

```
---
- hosts: server
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
  - name: Run runserver.sh and save the output of script
    shell: screen -dRR bash /home/dell/tester_server_2/runserver.sh
    async: 99999999999
    poll: 0
```

But this is not opening up a new screen session, although the top command on the remote vm shows that the script has started running

I also played around with other screen options as well such as -d -m -x etc

Answer (score 0):

I have an ansible task that launches a long running shell script from within screen so that I can check on its status at a later time. Here's how I have it defined:

```
- name: Invoke do-grails reset -solr
  command: /usr/bin/screen -d -m sudo -u czapp /usr/local/bin/do-grails.sh -i -y reset -solr
  async: 60
  poll: 0
```

Edit: All this command is doing is invoking screen to run a command in the background.  The command in this case is:

```
sudo -u czapp /usr/local/bin/do-grails.sh -i -y reset -solr
```

In my particular case I needed to run this shell script as a user named "czapp", hence my use of sudo.  You should be able to use the same basic approach for your command.  In your case you probably want to do something like this:

```
- name: Run runserver.sh and save the output of script
  command: /usr/bin/screen -d -m /home/dell/tester_server_2/runserver.sh
  async: 60
  poll: 0
```

By invoking screen with "-d -m" you are telling it to start in detached mode, so a new screen session is created that runs the specified command and control is immediately returned back to Ansible.